# I need to open a page then reload it after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, html, window, settimeout, reload

**UPDATE: Thank you to everyone who answered. I learned I can't do exactly what I was trying to do. Fortunately, I found some auto refresh extensions for Chrome that do what I wanted.**

Simple question. I don't code very much at all though. I'm trying to direct an html doc to immediately open a specific web page, then reload that same page in the same window after a specified amount of time. The following code works, but opens a new window, which is NOT what I want:

```
<script>
    window.open('https://www.google.com');
    setTimeout('window.location.reload();', 10000);
</script>
```

Then I tried using the following:

```
<script>
    window.location.href='https://www.google.com';
    setTimeout('window.location.reload();', 10000);
</script>
```

But this only opens the page. It does not reload it. What am I doing wrong? How do I do this right?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Once you redirect to another location, all the scripts on the current page stop. You can't run your own scripts in the google page.

Comment: Ah okay. Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important Edit:

This will only work if your code is at the arriving page. You cannot open a window and launch some code in that one.

---

In both cases, the first line in your script does something first.

On the first case, it opens a new window then reload the page after ten seconds.

On the second case, it immediately goes to google.

The second line should be enough to work.

Althought, I would advise you to do:

```
 setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.reload();
 }, 10000);
```

what you did is considered really bad practice.

Comment: No; navigating blows away your code.  You can't do that.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.location.href='https://www.google.com';
    setTimeout(function() {
       window.location.href='https://www.google.com';
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

Have you tried this?

I don't know if it helps, but maybe it's not a matter of reloading the page itself, but to run a function that updates some data in your view.

Comment: This won't work. Once you assign to `window.location.href`, the current page is unloaded and scripts stop.